# CentOS: Install packages listed in a text file?

Tags: centos, command-line, package-management, yum

I have an existing CentOS installation which I'd like to install extra packages to. The packages to be installed were supplied to me in a list, one package per line, which looks like:

```
....
Cluster_Administration-en-US.noarch
ElectricFence.x86_64
GConf2.i386
GConf2.x86_64
GConf2-devel.i386
GConf2-devel.x86_64
Global_File_System-en-US.noarch
ImageMagick.i386
...
```

Using this text file, is there a way to install every package listed? I suspect the list is actually a list of 'all' packages which could have been installed when the operating system was originally set up.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, do this:

`yum -y install $(cat file_name)`

Comment: This is much nicer, as it will look at all the dependencies at the same time, instead of figuring them out for every single package.

Comment: yes, that's true.

Comment: This is a really old question, but this certainly helped me. If you have a file with the packages separated by line feeds, you name need to do the following: 

    yum -y install $(cat filename cat | tr '\n' ' ')

Comment: Wow. So simple I could only google it instead of think of it myself.

Comment: Alas this won't work too well if the list of packages exceeds the command line maximum length.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `xargs`:

```
cat textfile | xargs yum -y install
```

Comment: There is nothing to concatenate - thus, `< textfile xargs yum -y install` is equivalent and saves a fork/exec.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this in command line.

```
for i in `cat textfile` ; do yum -y install $i; done
```

For every i in textfile, it does a yum -y install.

Comment: as Mafcin stated above this will do dependency check on every package ie. for each line.

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

```
list=""; for i in `cat texlive_packages.txt`; do list="$list $i"; done; yum -y install $list
```

Comment: This seems like a complicated way of doing `yum -y install $(cat file_name)` ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Read lines of the file into array `packageArr`. Then pass elements of the array as arguments to `yum install`.

```bsh
readarray -t packageArr <"${fileName}"
yum install "${packageArr[@]}"
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work if you just want to download the packages not install it.

for i in `cat package-list.txt` ; do yumdownloader $i; done

Comment: This is the same answer as two other answers but with different loop variables.